# jQuery-UI Dialog - Select don't work in titlebar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, titlebar

I want put a select in a title bar of a jQuery-UI dialog, but when the select is clicked it doesn't open dropdown menu.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="myDialog"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({});
var selLang='<select class="selLang "><option value="ita">ITA</option><option value="eng">EN</option></select>';
$("#myDialog").dialog("open");
$("#myDialog").dialog("option", "title", selLang);
$("#myDialog").append($(selLang));
$("#myDialog").dialog('widget').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').append($(selLang));
```

Can you see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s0hfbffv/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s0hfbffv/3/). 
It will allow you to drag modal also and allow to select dropdown from title.

```
$('.selLang').hover(function() {
    $("#myDialog").dialog('option', 'draggable', false);
},function(){
    $("#myDialog").dialog('option', 'draggable', true);
})
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I edited it though to fix the missing `)`